# Where is the file man?

Tags: linux, files, man

I have a question about the location of the file man, because some people told me it is in /usr/share/man, while other people told me: it's in usr/share/doc.
Where is it?

Comment: The places where manpages are looked for are defind in `/etc/manpath.config`. These usually are subdirectories of `/usr/share/man`, `/usr/local/share/man`etc., but also could be in `/usr/share/doc`, though this is not standard. `/usr/share/doc` usually contains other srots of documentations.

Comment: You might find it useful to research the `locate` command.  It may be necessary to download the package and run `updatedb` before it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man` is a command used for displaying manuals.  You very seldom have to care where the actual manuals are stored.

To get the manual for, e.g., the `ls` command:

```
$ man ls
```

To get the manual for the `man` command itself:

```
$ man man
```

If you have manuals stored in a non-standard location, for example `$HOME/local/share/man`:

```
$ env MANPATH="$HOME/local/share/man" man somecommand
```

The default `MANPATH` is set up using `/etc/manpath.config` on many Linux systems, and may be viewed with the `manpath` command.

The directory `/usr/share/doc` may contain documentation which is not in `man` format. This may be README files, copyright information, and other bits of info not necessarily directly related to how to use a piece of software.

Comment: Thank for answer me, but I'm asking what's the route?

Comment: @elisur Route? You mean path? Have a look in `/etc/manpath.config`. Also try the `manpath` command.